# Screen not running @reboot for python project

Tags: python, linux, cron, uwsgi

I have a python project that I need running on a screen using uWSGI, if I run the script:

```
screen -d -m uwsgi --emperor "/home/rrcms/wsgi.ini" --socket :8000 --chdir /home/rrcms/ --wsgi-file /home/rrcms/wsgi.py
```

It will create a new screen and run the script properly, but when I try to add it to crontab it won't even create the screen, this is the script I'm using:

```
@reboot screen -d -m uwsgi --emperor "/home/rrcms/wsgi.ini" --socket :8000 --chdir /home/rrcms/ --wsgi-file /home/rrcms/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Try replacing uwsgi with its absolute path

Comment: that actually worked, please reply as an answer so I can mark it as the answer @fedterzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `uwsgi` with its absolute path:

(get absolute path from terminal: `which uwsgi`)

`@reboot screen -d -m /home/user/venv/bin/uwsgi --emperor "/home/rrcms/wsgi.ini" --socket :8000 --chdir /home/rrcms/ --wsgi-file /home/rrcms/wsgi.py`